# Cannot change dir while connected to Archlinux vsftp server

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, vsftpd

I have Raspberry Pi B+ with Archlinux installed. I've installed and configured its vsftpd ftp server and I connect to it from WinSCP (running on Windows 7 PC). I would like to upload some file, but I cannot neither copy the file to root folder neither cannot change directory and then copy file. Why, can someone help me?

Comment: only `root` can write to `/`. is that the user you're using to connect?

Comment: yes, indeed, and I login with anyonimous into ftp client, maybe the problem is here?

Comment: anonymous is not the same as `root`. Do you have `write_enable=YES`? to use `root`, you have to allow `local_enable=YES` set in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`? if you want to use anonymous, use `anonymous_enable=YES
` and `no_anon_password=YES`. see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon)

Comment: I did as you sad, but still no result.

Comment: it's difficult to shoot into the blind? what are your errors. Can you log into the rasp using a a simple ftp client?

Comment: Why can't you change the directory and then copy the file?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is upload a few files every now and then, I suggest using [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/). I use it since I always need a terminal and rarely copy files. The nice thing about this solution is that it removes the need to have an ftp daemon running on the remote system.

I open an ssh session, check the "Display SFTP browser" option and then copy the files. I've never had to configure an FTP server.